# Where to get top 10 companies who have had paid the highest for PPC or CPC in Google Adwords

Tags: google, google-adsense, google-search-console, keywords

I want to know which company or website has paid the highest in a market for a particular keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at whose ads consistently appear in the top slot.